# Get data attribute for all matched elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have HTML like below:

```
<div class="test" data-file="1"></div>
<div class="test" data-file="2"></div>
```

I would like to get a list of all the data-file values.  I tried using, `$(.test).data("file")` but this only returns `1` which makes sense according to [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/) which states it will return `...the value at the named data store for the first element in the set of matched elements.`

Emphasis on `first`.

Is there any way to tell jQuery to pull all of the data values into an array?

Comment: use .map and solve ur query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create temporary array for that purpose:

```
var myArray = [];
$('.test').each( function() {
    myArray.push( $( this ).data( 'file' ) );
}); 
console.log( myArray );
```

Comment: I was typing this when you submitted.

Comment: Use `.map`! - Less steps, no need to declare an empty array before hand :D. I'd also include the `data` attribute in the selector, just to guarantee that each iteration of the element has a data attribute.

Comment: @tymeJV I know, I know, just as example of different approach :)

Answer (score 5):

Of course! Use `.map`

```
var dataValues = $(".test[data-file]").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("file");
}).get();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5muq33of/

Comment: The .test['dat-file'] will not be recognized...This wont work unless u modify it thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dataValues = $(".test[data-file]").map(function() {
    return $(this).data("file");
}).get();
console.log(dataValues);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test" data-file="1"></div>
<div class="test" data-file="2"></div>
```